# How to Use annotate function to in django for below condition?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Surface(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     surface_class = models.ManyToManyField(SurfaceClass, default=None)

class SurfaceGeometry(models.Model):
    surface = models.ForeignKey(Surface, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    geometry_parameter = models.ForeignKey(SurfaceGeometryParameters, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.FloatField()

class SurfaceGeometryParameters(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

`Surface.objects.prefetch_related('surface_class',Prefetch('surfacecorrelationcontroller_set'),Prefetch('surfacegeometry_set')).annotate(height=?).order_by('surface_class__name','-height')`

I want to take height(value) from SurfaceGeomentry model where Height is name of geometry parameter from SurfaceGeometryParameters models for Surface.

```
I can get a height from SurfaceGeometry like this.
SurfaceGeometry.objects.get(surface__id = 1, geometry_parameter__name__iexact= 'Height')
where surfcace__id's value 1 should come from parent query.
```

How I can achieve the this?

Comment: I am able to achieve it with OuterRef.

Answer (score 0):

Final Answer of this question after too many attempt is

```
surface_height_query = SurfaceGeometry.objects.filter(surface=OuterRef('pk'),geometry_parameter__name__iexact='Height') \
.values_list('value', flat=True)

return Surface.objects.annotate(height=Subquery(surface_height_query)).order_by('surface_class__name','height')
```

[Django Documentation for the same](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/)